# CMake Error: File /cmake/setup_custom_pythonpath.sh.in does not exist

Tags: ros-melodic, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following lines in my CMakeLists.txt and I am not able to use `catkin_make`.

```
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
   config/dyn_reconf.cfg
)
```

The full error message:

```
CMake Error: File /cmake/setup_custom_pythonpath.sh.in does not exist.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/dynamic_reconfigure-macros.cmake:42 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ../project/CMakeLists.txt:94 (generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options)
```

Here is my `dyn_reconf.cfg`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PACKAGE = "project"

from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *

gen = ParameterGenerator()

gen.add("Resizing Factor",   double_t, 0, "A float parameter to make the original image's resolution",  0.3) 
gen.add("Hough Circle Upper Threshold", int_t, 0, "One of the Hough parameters", 100)
gen.add("Hough Circle Lower Threshold", int_t, 0, "One of the Hough parameters", 30)
gen.add("Hough Circle Min Radius", int_t, 0, "One of the Hough parameters", 10)
gen.add("Hough Circle Max Radius", int_t, 0, "One of the Hough parameters", 30)

exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "project", "dyn_reconf"))
```

and this is how I imported it:

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.server import Server
from dyn_reconf.cfg import dyn_reconf
```

**EDIT:** Adding the rest of `CMakeLists.txt`:

**EDIT2:** Updated `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(project)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  image_geometry
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  dynamic_reconfigure
)

generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
   config/dyn_reconf.cfg
)

catkin_package(
   CATKIN_DEPENDS image_geometry  rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs dynamic_reconfigure
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_dependencies(project ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318918/cmake-error:-file-/cmake/setup_custom_pythonpath.sh.in-does-not-exist./) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-20**:
Can you show your `CMakeLists.txt`? Did this ever work, or is it a new package / have you just added dyn recfg to it?

According to [this](https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/blob/0556c0a0a8123c57250d41a889c2b65a2adfba16/cmake/dynamic_reconfigure-macros.cmake#L43), `${dynamic_reconfigure_BASE_DIR}` would have to be empty for this to happen, if I interprete things correctly.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-03-20**:
My package has been working all OK. Now that I want to use dynamic reconfigure, it doesn't compile. In other words, I am facing this error while trying to use dynamic reconfigure for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how you are even able to call `generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(..)`, but as explained in [the first tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile), you must add the `dynamic_reconfigure` dependency to your package, otherwise it won't work.

You have to add `dynamic_reconfigure` to the `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ..)` call in your `CMakeLists.txt` (and to your `package.xml` as a dependency).

Note: you also don't have a `catkin_package(..)` there, which you should probably add.

See also the Catkin documentation on `dynamic_reconfigure`: [Dynamic reconfiguration](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/dynamic_reconfiguration.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-03-20**:
I tried adding `add_dependencies(project ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})` but it throws the error of `Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target "project"`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-20**:
Ignore that bit for now. First get your dependency declarations correct.

Is this a Python package? Or have you not shown us your full `CMakeLists.txt`?

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-03-20**:
This is a Python package, and I did everything written in the page [above](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/dynamic_reconfiguration.html). The error in the above comment came after I followed the instructions. Anyway, updating the question so that you see the new `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-20**:
Don't add the `add_dependencies(..)` bit. That is for C++ packages only.

You don't need the `include_directories(..)` call either. Python doesn't use any of that.

---

Edit: I've submitted a PR to note that `add_dependencies(..)` is only for C++ packages ([ros/catkin#1001](https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/1001)).

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-03-20**:
Yes, that was the problem now. Thanks, now it's compiling.

EDIT: Great idea, that would save time for the future learners.